# For epimorphism $\theta:P \rightarrow M$, where $Ker\theta \ll P$, then if $P'\leqslant P$, $\theta(P')=M \Rightarrow P'=P$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I am reading into projective covers of modules and this statement arose after the definition, but I am not entirely sure how to show the statement to be true. (In context, $P$ is the projective cover of $M$)

Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that if $P$ is the projective cover of $M$, then no proper submodule $P'$ of $P$ surjects onto $M$. The key is to know that $Ker(\theta)\ll P$ means $Ker(\theta)$ is a *superfluous* submodule of $P$, i.e. for all submodules $L\subseteq P$, $P=Ker(\theta)+L$ implies $L=P$.

Suppose $P'\subsetneq P$ is a submodule and $P'\twoheadrightarrow M$.
We claim $P=Ker(\theta)+P'$. Let $x\in P$. If $x\in P'$, then $x=0+x\in Ker(\theta)+P'$. Otherwise, $x\in P\diagdown P'$ and hence $\theta(x)=\theta(x')$ for some $x'\in P'$, so that $x-x'\in Ker(\theta)$. Thus $x=x-x'+x'\in Ker(\theta)+P'$. This proves $P=Ker(\theta)+P'$.
 
Now since $Ker(\theta)\ll P$, we get $P'=P$, a contradiction.